# need change Google Maps example

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I found an example that suits me, but I can not understand how to change the search. There is a "spinner", it spelled out "types" of google maps dev, and the search goes only on them (that is, atm, bank, etc.), and I need to make so that the search was for "keywords" or "name". here is the link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-and-place-details-using-google-places-api-and-google-maps-android-api-v2/ , please help. it is very necessary to solve the problem, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I think you want to find out where to change the request for the Google API. So that's at this line:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?");
sb.append("reference="+reference);
sb.append("&sensor=true");
sb.append("&key=YOUR_BROWSER_API_KEY_FOR_PLACES");
```

That's where he builds the URL for the request. Then have a look at the [API Docs](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) and you'll be able to find what you want

Comment: Yes, I know of these lines ... but I could not write it "keywords" instead of "types". it is necessary to "spinner" work (as in the screenshot), but it has not been specified "types", and "keywords", and search for a map of places he worked ... so search works, but the standard "types" I do not like, we need own "keywords" .... canhelp?

Comment: Do not understand what you mean, just add a URL parameter

Comment: Here's the code that performs the search. Look for the "Types" search is set on them, need to save "spinner" seach. substituting types for keywords. I triyng sb.append("&keyword="+type); but its dont work

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                    sb.append("&types="+type);
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=YOUR_BROWSER_API_KEY_FOR_PLACES");

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get any response ?

Comment: sorry for my bad English. I did everything like in the tutorial, it works. but the search is performed by "types" I also want to search by "keywords". if look on <string> see what this is types for search, if i change <strings> for something like "new york", search dont work

Comment: because `New Work` is maybe conflicting with the location you set... Can it be ?

Comment: I do not think this is an example of speech, beat seach by nearby, in this example, but even if you change to say "mcdonalds", the search does not work, the markers do not appear. In this issue, for example, or there "gas_stations" tutorial of Google, the search shows all gas stations nearby, but if you what to search british petrolium gas stations, then a void

Comment: so can help with this?

Comment: or example with auto seach with one word